# Permanently redirect Jekyll pages to external site without markdown?

Tags: jekyll, redirect, github-pages

Using Jekyll/Github pages. As part of a content overhaul, we've moved a lot of pages to an external site. We'd like to clean up our Github pages repository and remove all purged files while providing a 301 redirect to the new domain where they now live.

The problem is that - according to my understanding of the docs - you must have a markdown file present with a `redirect_to` field. This defeats the purpose of purging the files in our repo. Is there a way to configure redirects from the `_config.yml` file or a plugin that allows me to do this from a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see how this can be possible on the GitHub platform. As you mentioned, you can use the `jekyll-redirect-from` [plugin](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/) but you cannot automate it through config or other data files because Jekyll sites are static and thus, the server will only look for the directory and an index file within it for each URL.

The only way you can achieve this without keeping the file structure is to move the site to a server where you configure URL rewrites within the web server such as Nginx or Apache.

Comment: Yea and looking through their supported plugins, I can't write a custom one either: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/ only a list of supported plugins https://pages.github.com/versions/. Server migration may be the choice here.

Comment: I had a similar issue with permalinks. Some URLs has a trailing backslash while some did not and this was affecting my SEO. I still kept my Jekyll site but it is now hosted on Firebase free for one year. I think they still have the offer through GCP (Google Cloud Platform). Look into it :) ON Firebase / GCP you can add URLrewrite rules.